# Statistical inferences on LME predictions

Tags: lme4-nlme, prediction

Suppose that under a linear mixed-effects model using the R package `nlme`:

```
library(nlme)
fm <- lme(distance ~ age, random=~age, data = Orthodont)
```

I can assess the predicted difference of "distance" between the two ages (8.5 and 13.4) as follows:

```
predict(fm, data.frame(age=13.4), level = 0) - predict(fm, data.frame(age=8.5), level = 0)
```

[1] 3.234907

However, is there a way to estimate the standard error for the above predicted difference?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the predictSE.lme function from the AICcmodavg package? 

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/AICcmodavg/versions/1.0/topics/predictSE.lme

Comment: @user3585829 Thanks! Yes, predictSE.lme can be used to get the predicted SE for data.frame(age=13.4) and data.frame(age=8.5) separately, but I cannot see how I could get the SE for their prediction difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `predictSE.lme` function from the `AICcmodavg` package will get you the predicted value and it's standard error. If you are comparing the two predicted values, couldn't you calculate the standard error of the difference between means as sqrt(se_1^2 + se_2^2) and derive your Confidence Intervals around the different from there?

```
library(nlme)
fm <- lme(distance ~ age, random=~age, data = Orthodont)

predict(fm, data.frame(age=13.4), level = 0) - predict(fm, data.frame(age=8.5), level = 0)


library(AICcmodavg)

mean_diff <- predictSE.lme(fm, data.frame(age=13.4), level = 0)$fit - predictSE.lme(fm, data.frame(age=8.5), level = 0)$fit
mean_diff

se_diff <- sqrt(predictSE.lme(fm, data.frame(age=13.4), level = 0)$se.fit^2 + predictSE.lme(fm, data.frame(age=8.5), level = 0)$se.fit^2)
se_diff


Low_CI95 <- mean_diff - 1.96*se_diff
High_CI95 <- mean_diff + 1.96*se_diff


list("Mean Difference" = mean_diff,
    "95% Confidence Interval" = c(Low_CI95, High_CI95))

$`Mean Difference`
[1] 3.234907

$`95% Confidence Interval`
[1] 1.952055 4.517760
```

Comment: Can we assume that the predicted distance is independent between the two ages of 8.5 and 13.4?

Comment: Not sure? Might need to know more about the population you are making the prediction on?

Comment: How about the dataset "Orthodont" provided by the R package `nlme`?

Comment: Ah, just read about it. No, I don't think you can assume independence. It is repeated measures on children over time (do you want to include the individual child in your mixed model too?).

Comment: I thought that the model `fm <- lme(distance ~ age, random=~age|Subject, data = Orthodont)` already accounted for the cross-subject slope (and intercept) variability through `random=~age|Subject`.

Comment: Sorry, your above model was only specifying age as a random effect.

Comment: Not sure what you mean: while `random=~age|Subject` is a random effect, `age` in this part `distance ~ age` is not considered as a fixed effect?

Comment: Your model in you question was specified as: fm <- lme(distance ~ age, random=~age, data = Orthodont). This model only has age as a random effect. It doesn't include subject. That was what I was referring to.

Comment: You can verify that the two models are EXACTLY the same: `random=~age` is just a shortened version of `random=~age|Subject`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that. Thanks. However, I don't think the independence assumption can hold here.

Comment: I agree, and that's why I asked the question in the first place. So still waiting for more suggestions....

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious now too. I can't stop thinking about it.